# Create an elements generator with an infinite list

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm playing with QuickCheck, and stumbled upon some strange behavior

```
sample $ elements [1..5]
```

works as expected, however

```
sample $ elements [1..]
```

hangs in ghci, even when using a finite type such as `Int`

```
sample $ elements [(1::Int)..]
```

Why doesn't it print arbitrary (pun intended :) large `Int`s?

**Update**

I've tested @amalloy's explanantion by using

```
sample $ elements ([1 .. ] :: [Int8])
```

which does terminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elements` chooses elements uniformly at random, which means on average it will be reaching `length / 2` items into the list. For infinite values this is impossible, and for large finite lists like `[1..] :: [Int]`, this is still reaching like 1 billion items in, one at a time through the linked list. Quite a slow operation!

Comment: Thanks, why is it "reaching length / 2 items" on average?

Comment: I mean, think about it. In a list with `N` elements, what is the average index? The middle is the average, and it's at index `N/2`. Since you're choosing uniformly at random, your average index will be the average index of the list.

Comment: Right, but why would you need to traverse the first `[len/2] - 1` items? If you know the maximum `Int`, you can get it in O(1) by dividing in 2. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm a begginer with haskell.

Comment: Lists in Haskell are linked lists, always.

Comment: I see, so even integer lists don't have random access? This sounds awfully inefficient.

Comment: You use something other than a list when you want random access. An array, for example.

Comment: @dimid It is indeed inefficient, when you need random access. In many cases, though, you don't. Also, consider simple code like `let list = ... in (1:list, 2:list)`. Linked lists can build the last pair in O(1), when arrays can not. And arrays can never express infinite (lazy) lists like `[1..] :: [Integer]`, which are sometimes convenient to use.

Comment: @chi _contiguous_ arrays can't do this, but [chunked arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree) can.

Comment: @amalloy people always say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381379/create-an-elements-generator-with-an-infinite-list#comment66090836_39381473), but nowhere in the Report does it say this (that I could find). "linked" lists specifically and crucially allow for an O(1) removal of any internal node, given a pointer to a previous one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `elements` is poorly documented. In addition to being non-empty, the argument should be **finite**. See the source code:

```
-- | Generates one of the given values. The input list must be non-empty.
elements :: [a] -> Gen a
elements [] = error "QuickCheck.elements used with empty list"
elements xs = (xs !!) `fmap` choose (0, length xs - 1)
```

It tries to compute the length of the input list, which will cause an infinite loop on an infinite list.

Comment: Actually, as amalloy pointed out, the list in question is finite due to the type `[Int]`. Depending on your machine, `Int` may be 32 or 64 bits. In the former case, a computer with a large amount of RAM may terminate (eventually). In the latter case, you will definitely run out of memory.