# How to use arbitrary for a infinite list?

Tags: list, variables, haskell, infinite

i have the following help function:

```
    -- Generator for variable names
instance Arbitrary VarName where
  arbitrary = VarName <$> elements ["A", "B", "_0", "_"]
```

for the following task:
"Define a function freshVars :: [Varname], which gives you an infinite list of variablenames in the following pattern:

[VarName "A",…,VarName "Z",VarName "A0",…,VarName "Z0",VarName "A1",…,VarName "Z1",…]"

How can i do this? i think i dont understand arbitrary properly.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: And why do you think you need `Arbitrary` for this task? Doesn't seem an appropriate tool.

Comment: As leftroundabout says, here the list is deterministic and describes the exact pattern.

Comment: If the job is just to define `freshVars`, you do not need `Arbitrary` at all, just elementary library functions such as `map`. But regarding Arbitrary versus infinite lists, there is this [earlier SO question #39381379](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381379/create-an-elements-generator-with-an-infinite-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make a list with `["", "0", "1", …, "9", "10", "11", …, "99", …]` with:

```
suffixes :: [String]
suffixes = "" : map show [0 ..]
```

Now that we have that, we can make a list comprehension that will construct strings with a prefix `Char`acter that will enumerate over `['A' .. 'Z']` and uses one of the items of the suffix. We can do that with *list comprehension*:

```
freshVars :: [String]
freshVars = [VarName (… : …) | … <- …, … <- … ]
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.